# How to make angular child scopes refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a template:

```
<div class="oss-object cp-def cp-row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" ng-init="viewables = getViewables(value.versions[0].objectInfo);">
        <div class="cp-def">
            {{value.info.name}} OssStatus: {{value.versions[0].objectInfo.status}}
            , 3D-Viewables:
                <select ng-change="viewableSelected(value.versions[0].urn, viewables, '3d')" ng-model="viewables.selected3d" ng-options="viewable as viewable.name for viewable in viewables['3d']">
                    <option value="">---Please select---</option>
                </select>
            , 2D-Viewables:
                <select ng-change="viewableSelected(value.versions[0].urn, viewables, '2d')" ng-model="viewables.selected2d" ng-options="viewable as viewable.name for viewable in viewables['2d']">
                    <option value="">---Please select---</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And when data gets updated (the data property used in the top `ng-repeat`) in my *controller* with a new data set, it doesn't automatically refresh the child scopes in the `ng-options`. which are derived from the data set. Does anyone know how to refresh child `scopes`? I have tried calling `$apply` and `$digest` but with no success.

Comment: How about updating `viewables` when updating `data` in the controller?

Comment: viewables is a property on the child scope within the ng-repeat isn't it? a new viewables property gets created within each ng-repeat loop, and iscalculated on sub properties of the value within data, and I would assume it isn't really reachable within the parent controller

Comment: Ah yes. The problem is probably that the `ng-init` does not get rerun. You could try to replace `viewables['3d']` in the `ng-options` with `getViewables(value, '3d')` and have the controller return the array. That should be properly updated.

Comment: can you post your controller code ?

Comment: @OmriAharon I did what you said in your last comment, works great!, drop an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @0xor1 Cool, will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you could try to replace `viewables['3d']` in the ng-options with `getViewables(value, '3d')` and have the controller return the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for `ngInit`, you'll see they basically say "never use this except in nested `ngRepeats`".
One way to do what you want is to create a controller for each repeated item, and create a `$watch` on the data that changes (or expression in this case), and set `viewables` equal to that.

eg

```
function ViewablesCtrl($scope){
   $scope.$watch($scope.getViewables, function(){$scope.viewables = $scope.getViewables($scope.value.versions[0].objectInfo);}
})
```

--

```
<div class="oss-object cp-def cp-row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" ng-controller="ViewablesCtrl()">
```